Integral formula for Hopf map in local coordinates appears to vanish
Let $f:S^3\rightarrow S^2$ be a smooth map and let $\Omega$ be a volume form on $S^2$. To compute the Hopf invariant $H$ of $f$, we can note that the pullback $f^*\Omega$ is exact and may be written as $\mathrm{d}\omega$ for some $1$-form on $S^3$, and then use the Whitehead integral formula:
$$
H = \int_{S^3} \omega\wedge\mathrm{d}\omega.
$$
This all makes sense to me, but it seems to go wrong when I try to work through to find an explicit formula for $\omega\wedge\mathrm{d}\omega$ in local coordinates.
Let $\boldsymbol{\lambda} = (\lambda^1, \lambda^2, \lambda^3)$ be local coordinates on $S^3$, and choose the standard spherical coordinates $(\theta, \phi)$ on $S^2$ so that the volume form on $S^2$ is given locally by $\Omega=\sin\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta\wedge\mathrm{d}\phi$. In these coordinates the map $f$ may be written as $f(\boldsymbol{\lambda}) = (\sin\theta(\boldsymbol{\lambda})\cos\phi(\boldsymbol{\lambda}), \sin\theta(\boldsymbol{\lambda})\sin\phi(\boldsymbol{\lambda}), \cos\theta(\boldsymbol{\lambda}))$. The pullback $f^*\Omega$ is then given by
$$
f^*\Omega = f^*(\sin\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta\wedge\mathrm{d}\phi) = \sin\theta(\boldsymbol{\lambda})\,\mathrm{d}\theta(\boldsymbol{\lambda})\wedge\mathrm{d}\phi(\boldsymbol{\lambda}) = \sin\theta(\boldsymbol{\lambda})\,\partial_i\theta(\boldsymbol{\lambda})\partial_j\phi(\boldsymbol{\lambda})\,\mathrm{d}\lambda^i\wedge\mathrm{d}\lambda^j
$$
where the sums over the indices $i, j = 1, 2, 3$ have been left implicit. (I will drop the explicit dependence on $\boldsymbol{\lambda}$ from now on for ease of notation.) The form $f^*\Omega$ is closed so is locally exact, and in fact it may be seen that
$$
\mathrm{d}\left[-\cos\theta\,\partial_j\phi\,\mathrm{d}\lambda^j \right] = \sin\theta\,(\partial_i\theta)(\partial_j\phi)\,\mathrm{d}\lambda^i\wedge\mathrm{d}\lambda^j-\cos\theta\,\underbrace{(\partial_i\partial_j\phi)\,\mathrm{d}\lambda^i\wedge\mathrm{d}\lambda^j}_0 = f^*\Omega,
$$
so we identify $\omega = -\cos\theta\,\partial_j\phi\,\mathrm{d}\lambda^j$ (the possible addition of a closed form is unimportant for the computation of $H$). However, if we now compute $\omega\wedge\mathrm{d}\omega$ we find
\begin{align}
\omega\wedge\mathrm{d}\omega ={}& (-\cos\theta\,(\partial_k\phi)\,\mathrm{d}\lambda^k)\wedge(\sin\theta\,(\partial_i\theta)(\partial_j\phi)\,\mathrm{d}\lambda^i\wedge\mathrm{d}\lambda^j)\\
={}& -\frac{1}{2}\sin 2\theta\,(\partial_i\theta)(\partial_j\phi)(\partial_k\phi)\,\mathrm{d}\lambda^i\wedge\mathrm{d}\lambda^j\wedge\mathrm{d}\lambda^k=0
\end{align}
which vanishes since $\partial_j\phi\,\partial_k\phi$ is symmetric but $\mathrm{d}\lambda^j\wedge\mathrm{d}\lambda^k$ is antisymmetric.
What's going on? What is the correct way to carry out this computation? I have a feeling that my error is to do with the fact that the expression $\Omega =\sin\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta\wedge\mathrm{d}\phi$ is only valid locally, but I am not confident in this matter.

Indeed, the form is exact in that coordinate chart, so the pullback is exact, hence closed.

It might help to use $S^3\subset \Bbb C^2$ and view $S^2$ as $\Bbb CP^1$. Try doing the Hopf map explicitly.

This very nice subject is masterfully treated in Masatsugu Minami, Dirac's Monopole and the Hopf Map, Progress of Theoretical Physics, Vol. 62, No. 4, October 1979 which you can find in the internet.

This is obvious to me now that I've taken a step back to think about it!
The form $\omega$ is itself a pullback, $\omega = f^*(-\cos\theta\,\mathrm{d}\phi)$, so
$$
\omega\wedge\mathrm{d}\omega=f^*(-\cos\theta\,\mathrm{d}\phi)\wedge f^*\Omega =  f^*\left[(-\cos\theta\,\mathrm{d}\phi)\wedge\Omega\right] = 0
$$
since $\Omega$ is a top-dimensional form on $S^2$. Instead of finding a (local) form $\eta$ on $S^2$ such that $\Omega = \mathrm{d}\eta$ and then pulling it back to $S^3$, it is necessary to solve the differential equation $f^*\Omega = \mathrm{d}\omega$ on $S^3$. The former construction can never yield a globally well-defined 1-form on $S^3$.
This also reveals another issue with my construction: $\Omega$ is closed but not exact so $\omega$ does not extend to all of $S^3$ smoothly. The form $(1-\cos\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\phi$ is merely a local gauge potential c.f. the Dirac monopole/$\mathsf{U}(1)$ bundle on $S^2$.
